# If not run after get-service in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to access the service status of the remote server. i wrote this

```
$ServerList = get-content -Path "c:\users\cont015\Desktop\ServerList.txt"
ForEach ($ServerName in $ServerList) 
{
  $Status= Get-Service -ComputerName $ServerName | ?{$_.DisplayName -like "SQL Server (*"} |        select Status | format-wide
  if($st -eq "Running")
  { 
    $SeverName
    $Status
  }
  else
  {
  }
}
```

it is showing

```
$Status= Get-Service -ComputerName $ServerName | ?{$_.DisplayName -li ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Service], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
```

in error. i don't know what i am missing. but when i run without if condition if shows proper output.

Comment: Where is `$st` coming from? You never define or use it anywhere other than the `if` condition.

Comment: Also, remove `format-wide`. The `Format-*` cmdlets are for **display** purposes only

Comment: it is $Status not $st

Comment: after removing format-wide i got output like status=running, which is not working for IF condition.

Comment: No, because with `select Status` you reeive an **object** with one property called `Status`. Do `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Status`

Comment: got the same result after make changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ServerList = Get-Content -Path "c:\users\cont015\Desktop\ServerList.txt"
ForEach ($ServerName in $ServerList) 
{
  $Status= @(
    Get-Service -ComputerName $ServerName -DisplayName "SQL Server (*" |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Status)
  if ("Running" -in $Status) 
  {
     [PSCustomObject]@{
        Server = $ServerName
        Status = $Status
     }
  }
  else
  {
  }
}
```

Explanation:

- [`Get-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Service) docs: `-DisplayName`
  Specifies, as a string array, the display names of services to be retrieved. **Wildcards are permitted** (used instead of `Where-Object` as such filtering is always faster).
- [Array subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#array-subexpression-operator--) `@( )`. -
  Returns the result of one or more statements as an array. The result is always an array of 0 or more objects (i.e. force Powershell to always return an array when a call returns only one object or even `$null`)
- Used `[PSCustomObject]@{}` in output instead of a sequence of strings (learn advantages at [Everything you wanted to know about PSCustomObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2)).